# FileNotFoundException: Error loading "Content\gParticle.xnb". File not found

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have moved an old project from my laptop to pc which has a newer version of visual studio and have had to reinstall xna and monogame. I have come across various issues in the process and still havent managed to fully play my game project.

The original version of monogame that was used was 3.0 and I know it has moved on since then that now templates in mgcb files. However the issue I am having is that when it gets to loading the first of many assets I get FileNotFoundException: Error loading "Content\gParticle.xnb". File not found.

I have checked the naming convention and the file is there and although is a .png I would expect it to look for .png files when it cant find any .xnb ones.

Here is an example of my code:
[ExampleCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSYl8.png)

Edited:
[Solution Explorer Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRwVa.png)

Comment: Could you expand the Solution Explorer more? I remember I had to add the files to a [Gamename].Content project in order to read them, that should also be the location where it converts uploaded files to .xnb

Comment: @Steven Heres hopefully a better view for you on the solution explorer. I have also made sure the image options for Copy to Output Directory is Copy Always

Comment: You reinstalled XNA? So are you still using XNA or are you using the latest version of monogame, since now you only add the nuget packages and really don't need to install anything (except for the content pipeline, and that being said, did you install it correctly)?

Comment: Make sure you didn't miss `Content.RootDirectory = "Content";` before loading the content.

Answer (score 0):

"I would expect it to look for .png files when it cant find any .xnb ones."

Your expectation is incorrect.

While it is possible to load a .png file directly. If you expect any amount of cross platform compatibility, add the png file to the .mgcb file and let it build an XNB file for the target platform.